# C Program- counting lines in text file incompatible with directory scan?

Tags: c, file, text, directory, lines

I'm trying to read a variable from multiple text files in a directory. When I run the code, it glitches after I try to read the number of lines in each text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{

  DIR *ptr;
  double variable;
  int n, i;
  FILE *f;
  char ch1;

  n=0;
  i=0;

  struct dirent *directory;
  ptr = opendir("faketext");
  while((directory = readdir(ptr)) != NULL)
  {
    if ( !strcmp(directory->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(directory->d_name, "..") )
    {

    } else {
      n++;
    }
  }

  rewinddir(ptr);

  char *filesList[n];

  //Put file names into the array
  while((directory = readdir(ptr)) != NULL) {
    if ( !strcmp(directory->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(directory->d_name, "..") )
    {}
    else {
      filesList[i] = (char*) malloc (strlen(directory->d_name)+1);
      strncpy (filesList[i],directory->d_name, strlen(directory->d_name) );
      i++;
    }
  }
  closedir(ptr);

  int filt_len[n];

  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    char buf[0x100];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "faketext/%s", filesList[i]);
    f = fopen(buf, "r");
    if(f == NULL){
      printf("Trouble opening file.");
    }

    for (ch1 = getc(f); ch1 != EOF; ch1 = getc(f)){
      if (ch1 == '\n')
        filt_len[i] = filt_len[i] + 1;
    }

    fscanf(f, "%lf", &variable);
    printf("%f\t%d\n",variable, filt_len[i]);
    fclose(f);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

This program works perfectly... if I don't include the line-counting function. And the line-counting function works well outside of this program- I've used it multiple times before to great success.

I'm currently running the program with four test text files, each with two or three variables inside. The output should be the first variable in each text file (a nonzero decimal), followed by the number 2 or 3.

When I run the program, this is the output:

0.000000        14

0.000000        35

0.000000        17

0.000000        4199674

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this isn't working? I don't understand why the two functions would work well separately but not together.

(New to C and self-taught.)

Comment: (Probably unrelated) After opening a file and testing the pointer with `if(f == NULL)`, you print an appropriate message *but* you still merrily let the function continue on that file pointer. Put in a `return 0` after the message.

Comment: What do your files look like? Add a few examples so we can check what your code does.

Comment: My files are basically just text files- a single column of two or three decimals, one decimal in each line. For example, my first text file has three numbers in a column: 17.01, 10.31, 74.656. So the code should print out: 17.01   3    when it comes to that particular file.

Comment: When you copy the file names to `filesList`, you don't null-terminate the strings. You allocate correctly, but after that you should either just `strcpy` or call `strncpy` with `strlen(...) + 1`. Better yet, use the POSIX function `strdup`, which will do all this -- allocation and copying -- for you.

Comment: Your `for` loop over `ch` consumes the file -- after it ends, the read position is beyond its end. The subsequent `fscanf`, whose return value you should check, will not find anything. You can `rewind` the file to start reading at the beginning again. (But you'll still have to check the return value of `fscanf`, so that you're sure that the first "word" in the file is a floating-point number.)

Comment: Thanks! I implemented rewind(f) after the line count function. The variables show up now, but the line count is still wrong.

Comment: When you create `filt_len`, the contents are uninitialised, that is they most likely contain garbage. You cannot initialise a variable-length array, but you should set `filt_len` to zero explicitly before your counting loop.

Comment: That works! Thank you.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>`  When compiling, enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the function: `getc()` (often implemented as a macro invoking `fgetc()`) returns a `int`, not a `char`, so this statement: `char ch1;`  should be: `int ch1;`

Comment: a directory entry can be several different kinds of things.  Strongly suggest (besides checking for `.` and `..` to also take into consideration the `struct dirent` field: `d_type` (although note that not all file systems actually implement that field.)

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*`, so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: rather than calling `malloc()`, followed by `strcpy()`,  suggest calling: `strdup()`

Comment: regarding: `if(f == NULL){
      printf("Trouble opening file.");`  This actually tells the user little to nothing about the underlying cause of the problem.  Suggest: `if(f == NULL){
      perror("Trouble opening file.");`  as this will properly output the error message to `stderr` rather than `stdout` AND will output the reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: regarding: `or (ch1 = getc(f); ch1 != EOF; ch1 = getc(f))`  the `EOF` is actually `-1`, which may (or may not) be properly compared, depending on if `char` has the default attribute of `signed` or `unsigned`.  To be safe (and make a proper check), declare `ch1` and `int` rather than `char`

Comment: regarding: `if (ch1 == '\n')`  note that a '\n' is actually a `int` value, so needs to be compared to an `int`.  Therefore declare `ch1` as an `int`

Comment: regarding: `if(f == NULL){
      printf("Trouble opening file.");
    }`  The code must not continue if the the file pointer `f` is NULL,  otherwise, any activity involving that file pointer will result in a seg fault event.  Suggest inserting the statement: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` before the closing brace '}'.

Comment: the posted code fails to pass the allocated heap memory pointers (gotten from calls to `malloc()`) to `free()`.  It is poor programming practice to let the system cleanup when the program exits.

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing the statement: `#include <math.h>`

Comment: many times, a text file will not have a '\n' (newline) on the very end of the file, so this code block: `for (ch1 = getc(f); ch1 != EOF; ch1 = getc(f)){
      if (ch1 == '\n')
        filt_len[i] = filt_len[i] + 1;
    }` will not result in the correct line count.  This will also not work if the file is not a 'regular' file  (cont)

Comment: (cont):  suggest replacing with: `for( int i=0; fgets( ...); i++ );` or something similar.

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(f, "%lf", &variable);`   This statement will produce garbage for most files.

Comment: The posted code is failing to check if the directory entry is actually the name of a 'regular' file.   If not a 'regular' file, do not open that file for reading.